# Google+ contact's phone number getting mixed up with operator's number

Tags: contacts, google-plus

One of my friend has written "not for all" in place of this phone number in his Google+ profile.

[image]

Now when his Google+ profile got synced with my contacts on phone a strange thing started happening. Whenever my operator(Vodafone) sends me SMSs regarding GPRS settings, billing info, etc. his name starts appearing in place of my operator's usual names that used to appear.

[image]

This is really confusing and disturbing sometimes.

I can't really ask my friend to edit his info on Google+ just for my sake, its completely his personal matter. Also its not possible to delete that particular field from the contact. So is there anything I can do from my side to prevent this mix up? The only thing that I can't do is un-link his Google+ contact. Any other suggestion or workaround is welcomed.

I am using a Moto G(1st Gen. Dual SIM) running Android 5.0.2.

Comment: Try adding Vodafone as a contact with the number the account texts come from.

Comment: @abraham the problem is the number from which the account related texts come is not shown. I though about something like this once but this was the reason I was not able to do anything about it. And its not a single number the numbers are different for bill related info, alerts, etc. So I need  to gather all those numbers under Vodafone. And I already have the operators number which is used for communicating with them on the SIM (It was provided on the SIM during the time of purchase).